# My google account is disabled

Tags: google

My google account is disabled. My mobile is working fine. I add another google account. Can I get all my apps to that account.

Comment: Are you talking about paid or free apps?

Comment: All apps. Mainly free apps.

Comment: Only paid apps are bound to an Google account. You can just remove the old account. The apps will stay.